# Why does IE8 fail to window.open() when viewing local HTML files (and how to fix it)?

Tags: javascript, html, windows, ie-developer-tools

Due to orders, I **must** test some pages from a **local file system** running Windows XP and IE8.  Firefox and other browsers can view the documents and javascript for opening new windows works.  However, with IE8, I get new window filled with some default error message, "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage".

Anyhow the first "launcher" html is located in a path like so:
C:\Documents and Settings\Tester1\My Documents\Sites\testsite\Launcher.html

Launcher.html has links which call window.open() with a URL of Target.html.  This is the point of failure.  The window opens, but contains only the error message.

Comment: That actually does work properly, so there must be something else going on. Post the code.

Comment: does your code include any calls to `window.resizeTo()` or `window.resizeBy()` ?  There is a known issue in IE that restricts access to these methods during the onload event (IIRC) they return *Permission denied* errors instead. see comments on this MSDN post: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536723%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: The httpErrorPagesScript.js error was indeed irrelevant.  The problem seems to be related to passing variables via the URL into the target.  The Launcher.html actually calls window.open() with a url like, Target.html?path=../../../content/file.xml  I've found that when the url is only Target.html?path=../content/file.xml it works, when it has more than one "../" it fails and if I show the address bar on the opened window I see that the path variable is in the address instead of the Target.html?path=../../content/file.xml

Comment: I've reached a conclusion that IE8 cannot handle URL variables whose values are strings that include multiple relative path sequences when running from the local file system.  That left two choices for work-around. 1)  Inject javascript into the target html to define the parameters I need it to receive  2) Continue passing variables via the url, but define the relative path portion in the target html.  Since that part of the path isn't changing anytime soon, and I don't know how to inject javascript I've settled for option 2.

Answer (score -1):

It's a security feature so a rogue site can't poke and execute malicious commands on your machine.

I'd reckon your best bet is to setup a simple server like XAMPP.. just for local testing.

Comment: This is not correct. A URL without a protocol and host is an implicit reference to the origin of the referencing page.